# Joining two different objects

Tags: mesh

How can I link those two separate objects by joining the mesh points? I tried <kbd>F</kbd> and *Merge at Center* but didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Join them in object mode to make them a single object, and then the merge operator should work.

Comment: that's it! thanks!